# Regex for north american phone numbers

Tags: php, regex

I have a following regex to validate north american numbers. Its working fine but I have small problem. 
Here is my code & regex:

```
$re = '/^\+(1)(((?!900)(?!976)[2-9][0-9]{2})((?!555)[2-9](?!11)[0-9]{2})[0-9]{4}$|\\\\+18([0,3-8])3((?!555)[2-9][0-9]{2})[0-9]{4})$/';
$str = '+18009876543';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

It return total 4 matches but I want only 3 i.e full match, group1(it will contain country code) & group 2(10 digit phonenumber).

This is what I am getting :

```
Array ( [0] => +18009876543 [1] => 1 [2] => 8009876543 [3] => 800 [4] => 987 )
```

But I want this:

```
Array ( [0] => +18009876543 [1] => 1 [2] => 8009876543 )
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/uEUi90/1

Comment: [`^\+(1)((?!900|976)[2-9]\d{2}(?!555)[2-9](?!11)\d{6}$|\\{2,}18[0,3-8]3(?!555)[2-9]\d{6})$`](https://regex101.com/r/xrj4jG/4) is shorter, faster, and only contains the groups you want

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\+(?:1)((?:(?!900)(?!976)[2-9][0-9]{2})(?:(?!555)[2-9](?!11)[0-9]{2})[0-9]{4})$|\\\\+18(?:[0,3-8])3(?:(?!555)[2-9][0-9]{2})[0-9]{4}$/
```

In PHP:

```
<?php
$re = '/^\+(?:1)((?:(?!900)(?!976)[2-9][0-9]{2})(?:(?!555)[2-9](?!11)[0-9]{2})[0-9]{4})$|\\\\+18(?:[0,3-8])3(?:(?!555)[2-9][0-9]{2})[0-9]{4}$/';
$str = '+18009876543';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

I made some groups non-capturing with `?:` to achieve this:

https://regex101.com/r/EfJ81h/1